How to constrain the success type?
I want to type a function that produces an effect but constrain the success type. However when I constrain the success type, how can I keep error and context of the effect unrestrained?
import { Context, Effect } from "effect";

export class ExternalDep extends Context.Tag("ExternalDep")<
  ExternalDep,
  { bar: Effect.Effect<{ foo: string }> }
>() {}

type Event<Payload = void> = { id: string; payload: Payload };
export type Handler = (input: { foo: string }) => Effect.Effect<Event<any>[]>;

const handler1: Handler = ({ foo }) =>
  Effect.gen(function* () {
    return [{ id: "test", payload: undefined }];
  });

// Not working because of the error
const handler2: Handler = ({ foo }) =>
  Effect.gen(function* () {
    yield* Effect.fail(new Error("Test"));
    return [{ id: "test", payload: { foo: "bar" } }];
  });

// Not working because of the dependency
const handler3: Handler = ({ foo }) =>
  Effect.gen(function* () {
    const dep = yield* ExternalDep;
    const foo = yield* dep.bar;
    return [{ id: "test", payload: { foo } }];
  });



TL;DR: TypeScript's inference is limited, as usual.
In this scenario, you use generics to retain type safety. For example, type SomeEffect<A extends Event<unknown>[], E = never, R = never> = Effect<A, E, R>.
In your case, you could do export type Handler<E = never, R = never> = (input: { foo: string }) => Effect.Effect<Event<unknown>[], E, R>;... but you'll still need to specify the generics, which is no fun, but unfortunately a fact of life (go thumbs-up #32794 and #10571 if you want to encourage change on this front). Keep in mind that this has nothing to do with your alias, the same thing happens with the Effect type as well—you'll need to specify all the types if you want to specify any.
Whenever I run into TS issues, I always check to see if Dan has anything to say, and he happens to have a post mentioning this. Take a read!
